# how to make a button enable after the textfield is filled out if we get data from segue

Tags: ios, swift

I have a login screen in my iOS app, there are following 2 ways to come to this login page:

1. from Welcome Screen
2. after the user finish the Sign Up process in the Sign Up Screen.

There are two textfield (email and password) and a button in the login screen. If the user comes from welcome screen, I want the button is only enable after the user filled out all the text field manually. I have no problem in this case. I use this line of codes

```
extension LoginlVC : UITextFieldDelegate {

    @objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // to make signUpButton enable when all text field is filled out

        if textField.text?.count == 1 {
            if textField.text?.first == " " {
                textField.text = ""
                return
            }
        }

        guard
            let email = emailTextField.text, !email.isEmpty,
            let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty
            else {
                loginButton.alpha = 0.4
                loginButton.isEnabled = false
                return
        }
        loginButton.alpha = 1
        loginButton.isEnabled = true
    }

}
```

but if the user comes from Sign Up Screen after they finish the sign up process, I use `prepare for segue` to send the email and password string from sign up screen to login screen, so the textfield in the login screen will automatically filled after sign up process.

I expect the button in the login screen is enable, but unfortunately, it didn't happen.

so how to make my button in the login screen is enable after receiving value from `prepare for segue` ?

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: yes thanks. have accepted your answer though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`editingChanged` callback gets called only when the user edits the `textField`s, not when you set the their `text` properties programmatically. That means that your prepare for segue code does not trigger `editingChanged` - thus the button won't update its state.

I suggest following. Refactor the existing code into following:

```
@objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // to make signUpButton enable when all text field is filled out

    if textField.text?.count == 1 {
        if textField.text?.first == " " {
            textField.text = ""
            return
        }
    }

    updateLoginButton()
}

func updateLoginButton() {
    guard
        let email = emailTextField.text, !email.isEmpty,
        let password = passwordTextField.text, !password.isEmpty
        else {
            loginButton.alpha = 0.4
            loginButton.isEnabled = false
            return
    }
    loginButton.alpha = 1
    loginButton.isEnabled = true
}
```

And then call the `updateLoginButton` in your prepare for segue code once you fill in the data to make sure that the `loginButton` is in correct state (and you can call it anywhere where you want to make sure the state is correct).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to viewDidLoad

```
loginButton.isEnabled = emailTextField.isEmpty  
loginButton.alpha = emailTextField.isEmpty ? 1.0 : 0.4
```